# Eight bar Linkage (Analytical solution)

Tags: applied-mechanics, kinematics

Good morning,

I'm trying to solve this problem of kinematics of an eight bar linkage through the analytical method.
I don't want that you perform the calculation, only I would like to have a advice how to divide the mechanism in analyzable subchains...
In the image below I'm able to recognise:

1. A0-A-C-B is an engine
2. E0-E-F is another engine

Actually I have calculated the position of point C on link 3, but then I have been stuck...

My problem is to get the position and so the velocity and acceleration of point D. E0-E with C-D seems a shaper chain but choosing so the calculations complicates a lot.
[image]

Thanks

Regards

Comment: please show how you have calculated the position at C (especially the form). It would help me to propose a path forward.

Comment: XC =XA+ AClength*cos(theta+psi); YC= YA + AClength*sin(theta+psi) where theta is the angle between reference X axis and AB and psi is the angle between AB and AC. If is not clear in the afternoon I will post an image. Thanks

Comment: Your question title is in all-capitals. Look at the home page and you'll see that yours is the only one. Hit the [edit] link. Note that your signature is automatically applied.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Transistor. I apologize but I'm a newbie. In the afternoon I will try to learn how to make my posts more readable.

Comment: @R.Schiavetta Have you found the angle of BA from point B?

Comment: @NMech No Sir,  to calculate the angle of AB with the horizontal Axis if have used the engine chain equations. First I have calculated the distance of the slider B from the origin and using this result I have calculated the cos and the sine of the angle of AB with the horizontal. Then I have calculate the angle itself. In the late afternoon I will try to write the equations I have used. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would try to determine the angle that link 3 forms with the horizontal.

This can be easily determined because:

$y_A = l_{A0-A}\cdot \sin(45^o)= l_{A0-A}\cdot \sin(\theta_B) $

Where : $\theta_B$: is the angle that AB forms with the horizontal axis.

You can solve this to find $\theta_B$ (and from that the location of B).

---

Then I would try to solve this using [homogeneous tranformations](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node111.html).

I would find the coorodinate for D as part of the following links

- B-C-D
- E0-D

The coordinates for point D should all be the same, but they will be expressed in different rotational angles :

- for $E_0-D$,
- of C-D
- of B-A (which you know from the previous step - see above).

From that you would have 2 equations (one for $x_D$ and one for $y_D$) and two unknowns, which you can solve numerically.

Comment: yes you are right Sir. A system of two trigonometric equations must be solved numerically to find the angle between CD and horizontal and the angle between horizontal and E0D. After the CD angle with the horizontal has been found the problem become straightforward. At first sight I hoped there was a simpler solution. In the next days I will perform the calculation and then I will post the solution (if I achieve the result). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the time to write down the solution and the Visual Basic Macro in excel to implement the Newton Method
Once you have found easily Xc and Yc...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]